# Can I configure SASS such that the scss files aren't in the web root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

It looks like SASS by default exposes scss files which I find rather obnoxious. Is there a way to configure SASS to look for scss files in a folder that's not in the web root but compile them into the `public/stylesheets` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

If you use Compass, then you'll have a file /config/compass.rb that'll look like the following. Here I have my sass files in app/stylesheets and saving compiled in tmp/stylesheets (to help with heroku deployments)

**/config/compass.rb**

```
# This configuration file works with both the Compass command line tool and within Rails.
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :rails
project_path = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.root
#project_path = RAILS_ROOT if defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "tmp/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
environment = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.env
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this without Compass?

Comment: @Alex -- You could use sasswatch and manually copy the files from one directly to the public/stylesheets.

Comment: (obviously this question/answer is for Rails 3.0 and below). Rails 3.1 has the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but it's actually simple to do, you just pass the directories through to sass instead of specific .scss like so;

sass --watch /location/to/you/scss/:/location/to/your/css

Then any changes to scss will be saved into your css directory and it will also follow the same structure of your scss directory.